# Why does sbt download a different Scala version than the one in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

The build.sbt already set

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

However, whenever i run sbt where the build.sbt resides, I always get this error

```
org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5: configuration not found in
org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5: 'master(compile)'. Missing
configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalaz#scalaz-
effect_2.10;7.1.0 compile
```

At the start, it's actually getting the version 2.10.5

```
Getting Scala 2.10.5 (for sbt)...
```

Now I cannot proceed.  I am running in my macbook.

Comment: can you post your full build.sbt definition? And how did you install sbt on your machine?

Comment: SBT itself needs Scala to compile your build, and it's not necessarily the same as the one used to compiled the project sources. Check your SBT version.

Comment: sbt version 0.13.12, i just installed it first time in my macbook via "brew sbt install". Prior to that, i installed homebrew cause my macbook doesn't have the brew command. Then I am trying to import a project from coursera tutorial in intellij but i keep on getting this error even if the build.sbt already set the scalaVersion to be 2.11.7

Comment: I think i found the reason.  There's a file named "build.properties" that comes with the codes that I am trying to import.  The original value is "sbt.version=0.13.9"... so what I did is I tried to change it to "sbt.version=0.13.12"... also I tried setting scalaVersion := "2.11.8" although i think 2.11.7 will do... i can now build the whole project :)

Answer (score 11):

sbt and your application (managed by sbt) have different requirements for Scala. They both Scala applications so they surely need a Scala runtime.

sbt uses a fixed version of Scala and all the plugins you could ever install in your project should be compatible to that particular Scala version. You cannot change the Scala version for sbt. It's "burried" in the code and not something users should change.

Your Scala/sbt projects can however use whatever they want for Scala. It's a separate concern. You can use `build.sbt` and `scalaVersion` to set your Scala version.

Having said that, at the very beginning, sbt will always download its own internal dependencies, Scala including. It is then saved in `~/.sbt/boot`.

```
➜  $ ls -l ~/.sbt/boot
total 424
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff       0 13 sie 20:22 sbt.boot.lock
drwxr-xr-x  4 jacek  staff     136  6 wrz  2015 scala-2.10.4
drwxr-xr-x  4 jacek  staff     136  2 wrz  2015 scala-2.10.5
drwxr-xr-x  4 jacek  staff     136 31 sty  2016 scala-2.10.6
drwxr-xr-x  4 jacek  staff     136  3 lis  2015 scala-2.11.5
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff  217029 20 lip 10:37 update.log
```

Depending on the sbt version you use, you may see different Scala versions being downloaded but they are *internal* to sbt. You should not be concerned with that. Just accept it :)

p.s. The versions of Scala used by sbt internally are not at all different from the ones you may have downloaded already for your Scala/sbt projects.

Comment: are sbt scala versions different from the scala downloaded from scala-lang.org ?